# export data outside of function dart

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Hello im pretty new to flutter and dart
and i wanted to do something with my database

i have this code to get a post

```
makePostRequest(int id, String type, String api) async {
  final uri = 'url';
  final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
  String body = "id=" + id.toString() + "&api=" + api + "&type=" + type;
  final encoding = Encoding.getByName('utf-8');

  Response response = await post(
    uri,
    headers: headers,
    body: body,
    encoding: encoding,
  );

  int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  String responseBody = response.body;
  print(statusCode);
  //print(responseBody);
  return responseBody;
}
```

and in initState i want to get it out to put it inside of my widget but i dont know how to do thats

```
Map<String, dynamic> reponseJson;
  @override
  void initState() {
    makePostRequest(
            widget.id, 'get-one', 'api_key')
        .then((value) {
      //print(value.toString());
      String jsonTxt = value;
      Map<String, dynamic> valueDBB = jsonDecode(jsonTxt);
      //print(ValueDBB['name']);
      reponseJson = valueDBB;
      print(reponseJson);
      return valueDBB;
      //i get the value here
    });
    //but not here
    super.initState();
  }
```

please help i locked on it more of 1 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). This widget allows you display some 'placeholder' widget while passed Future is in progress. Then, after Future si completed, builder will give you its return data and you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: i follow this tutorial thanks a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abxEKgeXGVE